# Low memory warning for NSObject

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, nsobject, low-memory

I have a subclass of NSObject, it is a singleton which loads a list of images into memory, either from hard drive or downloads them from the internet.

I want to release the images stored in memory if the app recieves a low memory message, like in a UIViewController. (it then gets the images from hard drive when it next needs them).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can implement `-applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` method in your application delegate and free memory there. Or you can make your singleton object listen to `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` notification and free memory in notification handler.